# SQL Server - Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46 Reason for this

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

My production SQL Server logs (SQL Server 2012 SP4 Enterprise edition) are showing a lot of intermittent errors like this. Also it is showing definition as below

> Login failed for user 'MyUser'. Reason: Failed to open the database 'MyDB' configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: XX.XXX.X.XX]

We have multiple application server using same connection string only few is having this issue.

I have verified Login, for this login ('Myuser' default database is 'master' and in the user mapping tab master is not mapped to this login but 'MyDB' is mapped with db_datareader & db_datawriter

1. What is the exact reason for this error ?
2. How we can resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is the error number and state preceding the message text? [This thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41820/connection-pools-being-reset-with-error-18056-severity-20-state-46-perfm) might help.

Comment: That's actually in the title, @DanGuzman *"Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46"*

Comment: @Larnu, thanks, missed that. I generally look at the question rather than title for detailed info.

Comment: Agreed, it should be in the question as well, @DanGuzman .

Comment: The default database of the MyUser login may be set to MyDB, but does MyDB actually have a database user mapped for the MyUser login?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, 'MyDB' is having database user 'Myuser'